# Clicking id with random number in c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium

Using c# winforms and selenium webdrivers.

I've tried this

```
driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ad-ttl']/a")).Click();
```

in order to click it but i didn't work.

HTML Code :

```
<div id="yui_3_10_0_1_1418194162300_146" class="ad-ttl"><a id="yui_3_10_0_1_1418194162300_145" href="http://ri.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrTcdjy7IdUt3sATg9jmolQ;_ylu=X3oDMTB2MDNwMXMxBHNlYwNvdi10b3AEY29sbwNncTEEdnRpZAMEcG9zAzE-/RV=2/RE=1418222962/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2f2668877.r.msn.com%2f%3fld%3dd33WakoDkJAIMxn5dGh8YwQDVUCUx0AKspPeVBIRqpFXcgYxytW-8aith7k2jbZMjUQNoLg76hIiV1F-jmHcvooccYvps7YCw2Ma04LDJIzxVXvVI1D8uWvNQZu6l6BzAZyCkpSURwY7WpZxCcUbZvL4AqxnA%26u%3dwww.teamspiritandfitness.com%252flebron-james-jerseys%252f/RK=0/RS=7FYmf.oFNCuguXRDjriSVwIXsLQ-?p=Lebron+James+Cleveland" target="_blank" class=""><strong>LeBron</strong> <strong>James</strong> Jerseys $89 - All Stitched and Free Shipping</a></div>
```

As you can tell the ID is never the same but it always has "yui" in it and the class clicking above didn't work. href always changed as well, so any sollution to this? Basically everything above it always changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these below codes to click on the link:-

**1-** Checks for element with **tag 'a'**, whose **id starts with 'yui'**, and having ** two child elements 'strong' with innerHTML/text as 'LeBron' and 'James' respectively**:-

```
driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[starts-with(@id,'yui') and //strong[.='LeBron'] and //strong[.='James']]")).Click();
```

**OR**

**2-** Checks for element with **tag 'a'**, whose **id starts with 'yui'**, and contains **'href' attribute with value containing the text '?p=Lebron+James+Cleveland'**:-

```
driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[starts-with(@id,'yui') and contains(@href,'?p=Lebron+James+Cleveland')]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub string matching in "**CSS**".

- matching prefix (as your id always contains 'yui')

  css=div[id^='yui']a

referred from :

https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Regards

Comment: driver2.FindElement(By.XPath("css=div[id^='yui']a")).Click(); ??? How do i imply this into c#

Comment: driver2.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^='yui']a")).click();

Comment: Didn't work. It gave me Exception error when doing it.